# Update specifc rows using SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to read through all the records in a table and for each record, if a certain condition is met, set a flag on that record with a true or false value. What happens is that my method inserts true for every record.

How do I make my method insert true or false depending on the condition?

For example, if I have a value of 11 in the `Code` column then insert a true into the `Flag` column for that record, but if the `Code` column has a value of 7 then insert a false instead.

Query:

```
string select = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
```

Method to read the records:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sdr["Code"].ToString()))
        {
            C_E = "0";
            this.Update(C_E);
            //ViewBag.Message = "cero";
        }
        else
        {
            C_E = sdr["Code"].ToString();
            this.Update(C_E);
            // ViewBag.Message = C_E;
        }

    }
}
```

Method to update the table:

```
private string Update(string C_E)
{

    ReglaController re = new ReglaController();

    string query = "UPDATE Movies SET Flag = @code";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        //command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = ("o");
        command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = re.Condition(C_E);

        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }

    return C_E;
}
```

Method to test the condition:

```
public string Regla_4(string C_E)
{
    string query = "SELECT Emp.Code FROM Empresas WHERE Emp.Code = @codigo";
    string R2 = "l";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        command.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = C_E;

        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {

            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                R2 = "True";
            }
            else
            {
                R2 = "False";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, why not just have a computed column? `ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD flag AS CASE code WHEN 7 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;`; You can use the same `CASE` expression in an `UPDATE`, of course. You certainly don't have to pull all of the rows to the application and update them one by one.

Comment: In any case , an UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause updates the whole table's column with the value passed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your update statement as shown below

```
string query = "UPDATE Movies SET Flag = CASE WHEN Code = 11 then true case when Code = 7 then false end";
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: That is syntactically incorrect and also suffers the same problem as OP's version - it updates every row in the table (assuming it passed syntax checking and executed).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your update query does not tell the database which row to update, so it updates the entire table. You need to tell it which row to update by including a WHERE clause.